# File system Object - QTP not able to open file on desktop

Tags: qtp, filesystemobject

```
Set  fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

set t  = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\manisha\Desktop\My.txt",True)

Set t = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\manisha\Desktop\My.txt", 1)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not able to open" -- what error message do you receive? What did you try to simplify the error scenario?

Comment: And actually i dont know why my question was edited, I had added some more detail to the question so tht its easily understandable. But as logged in after so long & see tht its edited & now it even took me some seconds to understand the question

Comment: Lol. So where's your edit?

Answer (score 0):

Try this--->

```
set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
set file1 = fso.createtextfile("C:\rahul1.txt" , True , false)
```

Comment: How does this help the asker?  You A) added an extra argument without explanation what this does and B) opened a file at the root of the drive, not the desktop.